# Hey, i am creating a game with similar context to angry birds, in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i am creating a game with similar context to angry birds, but i want to use pictures of objects rather than display objects in corona sdk. Thanks

example:

```
circle = display.newCircle(60, 70, 20 );
physics.addBody(circle, "dynamic",{density= 1.0, friction = 1.0, bounce = 1, radius = 10})
```

instead of using this as an object which moves on the screen, how can i use a picture

Comment: There must be some function to load and draw pictures, look on corona's wiki.

Comment: what's wrong with using display.newImage()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
display.newImageRect ( "path/to/your/image.png", 20, 20 )
```

where `20` and `20` are width and height of your image.